# How do I set Thunderbird to open links in Opera?

Tags: configuration, thunderbird, opera

Because it's almost obvious that either Thunderbird or Firefox freeze my whole system after some time, I'd like to not use FF at the moment and let Thunderbird run only for a short time as long as I check e-mails. Thunderbird web links should be opened with opera from now. For that I went in Thunderbird to Preferences->Advanced->General->Config Editor and set the following:

```
network.protocol-handler.app.http -> /usr/bin/opera
network.protocol-handler.app.https -> /usr/bin/opera
network.protocol-handler.warn-external.ftp -> true
network.protocol-handler.warn-external.http -> true
network.protocol-handler.warn-external.https -> true
```

Moreover I changed in Gnome in System->Preferences->Preferred Applications Opera as web browser and I checked in FF that it should warn if FF is not the default browser (obviously it isn't anymore).
Unfortunately all of these settings doesn't work. Thunderbird still opens web links with FF.
Any explanations why? (I already restarted Thunderbird although I don't have to, but no effect)

Comment: What is the output of these two commands? `update-alternatives --display gnome-www-browser`, `sh -x /usr/bin/sensible-browser www.google.com`?

Comment: The 1st command shows the /usr/bin/firefox is linked. The 2nd command has the following output: `+ URL=www.google.com
+ test -n 
+ test -n :0.0
+ test -n this-is-deprecated
+ test -x /usr/bin/gnome-www-browser
+ exec /usr/bin/gnome-www-browser www.google.com
LoadPlugin: failed to initialize shared library /home/markus/.mozilla/plugins/nppdf.so [/home/markus/.mozilla/plugins/nppdf.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32]`

Answer (score 1):

[image: Preferred Applications]

Search for it in Unity.

Comment: simplest answer that works fine, at least here in 11.10

Answer (score 0):

To always launch opera instead of firefox you can do the following:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gnome-www-browser
```

and choose the entry with opera.
If the command says something like `There is only one alternative in link group gnome-www-browser` you have to manually add opera via

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gnome-www-browser gnome-www-browser /usr/bin/opera 90
```

and retry the first command.